# Is it possible to put a captcha in my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, captcha

I'm creating a voting system in my extension and if its possible I would like to add captcha to restrict people from voting again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

It depends on where exactly in extension (content script, popup view or some custom page) you will have voting component, but in general, it's like a regular web application.

Comment: I would put it in content script?

Comment: Yes, you can put/insert a DOM elements with content scripts. You can check official [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).